# MEF [Import] C# Example

Tags: c#, syntax, import, mef

I am having a problem with extending some existing C# code.

There is an instance of a manager class exported from one class.
It is successfully imported into several other classes using:

```
[Import]
private Manager manager = null;
```

I have added the same code to a new class.  It compiles well, but at runtime the reference is always null.

I am obviously missing something.

**What I'd really like to see is the minimum code (two classes) needed to do an import.**
It doesn't have to do anything except create and export an object (preferably not a string nor a simple value) in one class and show it is non-null when imported to another class.  (I've been getting lost in the details of other examples trying to show functionality rather than just a usable syntax.)

Please note that I need to see an example using [Import], not [Import(type)].

Thanks.

Comment: If the answer I supplied is sufficient, you should mark it as answered... just an FYI :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [Import]
    private Manager manager; //Setting it to null is redundant.
}


[Export]
public class Manager
{
}
```

You'll also need to setup your container. There are frameworks that make it easier to wireup everything, but if not. It's not difficult:

At the start of your application you'll need to fill in your catalog:

```
//http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

//Add AssemblyCatalogs (Single) or DirectoryCatalogs (Multiple)
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IManager).Assembly));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"myimports\"));

//Don't do this (including the same assembly twice)
//catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Manager).Assembly));

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.composeParts(this);
```

---

But, you should really take advantage of interfaces for importing/exporting.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [Import]
    private IManager Manager;
}

[InheritedExport]
public interface IManager { }

public class Manager : IManager { }
```

---

Now, as far as stating a name and type, that is not necessary, but it's good if you plan on having similar exports that you need to distinguish.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    //This is for the specific AdvancedManager
    [Import("AdvancedManager", typeof(IManager))]
    private IManager AdvancedManager;

    //This is for the specific SimpleManager
    [Import("SimpleManager", typeof(IManager))]
    private IManager SimpleManager;

    //If you don't mark it as ImportMany this will fail because now there
    //are 2 non-specific IManager exports.
    [ImportMany]
    private ICollection<IManager> AllManagers;
}

[InheritedExport]
public interface IManager { }

//This will export out as an IManager and a specifically named IManager
[Export("AdvancedManager", typeof(IManager))]
public class AdvancedManager : IManager { }

//This will export out as an IManager and a specifically named IManager
[Export("SimpleManager", typeof(IManager))]
public class SimpleManager : IManager { }
```

Comment: Good answer but I'm not sure what PackageCatalog and the related stuff is.  It's not part of MEF.  In a preview version of MEF for Silverlight we had a PackageCatalog I think, but it is now called DeploymentCatalog and the APIs have changed somewhat.

Comment: I couldn't find PackageCatalog in the project.  Good to know it has changed.  I do see DirectoryCatalog, AssemblyCatalog, and AggregateCatalog in the project.  I'm still trying to get my head around this.

Comment: Ah yea, sorry... AggregateCatalog (a collection of other catalogs), DirectoryCatalog (imports the assemblies of a directory), AssemblyCatalog (imports a single assembly). Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

manager must be a property. try
`[Import]
private Manager manager { get; set; }`